# What exactly is a contradiction and how does it differ from falsity?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge about the terminology of formal logic. I am only interested in informal logic to the extent that a practicing mathematician needs it to proceed. Despite years of experience in mathematics, I am finding myself confused about what a contradiction means. According to [this site](https://criticalthinkeracademy.com/courses/propositional-logic/lectures/51567),

> A contradiction is a conjunction of the form "A and not-A"... So, a contradiction is a compound claim, where you’re simultaneously asserting that a proposition is both true and false.

I doubt that this is mathematical definition though, as Wikipedia's [article on contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contradiction) defines that

> a proposition is a contradiction if false can be derived from it, using the rules of the logic. It is a proposition that is unconditionally false

Two questions:

1. Main question: I'm confused as to the difference between a contradiction and a false statement. If I say that $x\in S\wedge x\not\in S$ then is this a contradiction or a false statement? There seems to be two ideas at play, one being a statement that is simply false like "The sky is red" versus something like $P\wedge \neg P$ where the $P$ can be any statement with a true/false value like a proposition or quantified predicate but regardless of whether $P$ is $0$ or $1,$ the value of $P\wedge\neg P$ is $0 $ (false). In the former case, there is no varying in the underlying components whereas in the latter we compute a truth table to find that we always get $0.$ I am running into the issue of distinguishing between the two because this article on [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction) uses the $\bot$ symbol and I don't know whether it is refering to a false statement or a logical contradiction, where by a false statement I mean something like "The sky is red" and by a contradiction I mean a statement like $P\wedge\neg P$ whose truth table has all $0$'s in the final column (I don't know if these are the right definitions for the terms).
2. Side question: Are all contradictions, that is those statements that evaluate to a truth table of all $0$'s in the final column, logically equivalent to a statement of the form $P\wedge \neg P$? A counterexample or proof would be appreciated.

Comment: Prove that $P \wedge \neg P$ implies $\bot$. The two are equivalent. Is it clear now?

Comment: Many statements are false under one but not all particular truth-value assignments.  A contradiction is false under all possible truth value assignments.  E.g., $p\to q$ is false only when $p$ is true, but $q$ is false.  However, $p \land \lnot p$ is false, no matter the truth value of $p$.  So a false statement, under only some but not all truth value assignments to the variables, is not a contradiction.  But a contradiction is always false, under every truth value assignments to the variables.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm afraid not. Is that in reference to the second question? What exactly is meant by $\bot$? Since $P\wedge \neg P$ implies anything by the principle of explosion, I guess it can prove anything but I don't really know what $\bot$ means.

Comment: Favst  Some statements can be false *sometimes*, but not *always*.  $p\to q$ is true alot, but not always.  $p\land q$ is false a lot, but not always.   A contradiction is always false.  The truth table of a contradiction ends with the rightmost column evaluating to FALSE in every row.

Comment: @amWhy the "sometimes" and "always" makes me wonder what is the thing that is changing. Are we talking about a generic proposition that can have 0's and 1's assigned arbitrarily to its components and we always get 0 (false) in the end for a contradiction?

Comment: See my last comment, @Favst. But yes, if whatever you assign the variables (0 or 1), in every possible way, we always get 0, then we have a contradiction.  If you sometimes get 1, it is not a contradiction, but is a statement which can be false sometimes.

Comment: @amWhy ok so that agrees with what I assumed what a contradiction is. The reason it bothers me is that "proof by contradiction" uses a contradiction, but that contradiction is usually not something that can be given varying true/false values. Usually in a proof, we get something like a statement and its opposite, not a generic proposition that has a truth table.

Comment: But the truth table of a statement $p$ and it's negation $\lnot p$, when arrived at in a proof, define $p\land \lnot p$ to be a contradiction.

Comment: @amWhy Ok so to be clear, let's say that I get to $x>3$ and $x\le 3$. To derive the truth table of this, would I call the first one $P$ and the second one $\neg P$ and assign $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ to them and derive the truth table like that?

Comment: Yes, that works.  Because you're testing the conjunction $P\land \lnot P$...  under each and every truth value assignment you list, the proposition is false.

Comment: Favst  Have you learned the distinction between tautology, contingency, and contradiction?  The first is a statement, like $p\lor \lnot p$ that is true no matter what.  The contingent statements can sometimes be true, but not always.  Contradictions, like $p\land \lnot p$ are false no matter what.

Comment: @Favst Note that we need to be careful about this: we have to define "$<$" and "$\le$" properly in order to get a contradiction (namely "$x<y$" should mean "$y\le x$ and $x\not\le y$"). For example, "$x\le y+1$ and $y\le x+1$" is **not** a contradiction since that sentence is true in certain models (where "$\le$" and "$+$" are interpreted rather oddly - but these models still count).

Comment: @Noah  Note the OP's comment testing the conjunction $x>3$ and $x\leq 3$.  One is the negation of the other.

Comment: @amWhy great, that makes sense then. I was confused about whether 0's and 1's can be assigned like that in a proof in practice like that, but now I get it. Yes, I am familiar with that terminology. Now I'm just wondering whether every contradiction is the conjunction of a statement and its negation. Qiaochu Yuan seemed to be saying about that but I didn't understand his very brief statement.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I wasn't disagreeing with them - I was just pointing out that we need to be careful to check how we've defined $<$ after all.

Comment: @Favst  Every contradiction can be reduced to a statement of the form $P\land \lnot P$

Comment: @Noah, okay, you had me scrambling to re-read the post and comments, in case I missed something.  No problem!

Comment: @amWhy excellent. If you post a correct proof of that, I would be glad to accept it since you answered my first questions as well.

Comment: @Favst  e.g., $(p\to q)\land (p\land \lnot q)$ is a contradiction.  Not the right hand side can be written, via demorgans as $\lnot (\lnot p \lor q)$, and the left hand side is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$.

Comment: "The sky is red" is a contingent statement, it may be false on earth but true on another planet. A contradiction is false in all models that satisfy the axioms of the structure being discussed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. Put simply, a contradiction is a sentence that is *always* false. More precisely,

> A statement is a contradiction iff it is false in all interpretations.

In propositional logic, interpretations are valuation functions which assign propositional variables a truth value, so a contradiction comes down to having 0's as the final column in all rows (= valuations) of the truth table.
In predicate logic, interpretations are structures consisting of a domain of discourse and an interpretation function defining a mapping from symbols to objects, functions and relations on it, so a contradiction is a statement which evaluates to false no matter the choice of objects and interpretation of the non-logical symbols.

Take the expression $\exists x (x < 0)$, for instance: This sentence is false in the structure of the natural numbers, but true when we evaluate it in the integers, or under some none-standard interpretation of the natural numbers where e.g. the symbol $<$ ist taken to mean "greater than". The statement is not valid (= true in all structures), but it is not contradictory (= false in all structures), either: While it may be coincidentally false in some particular structure/the situation we're currently interested in, it is *logically possible* for it to become true.
On the other hand, $\exists x (x < 0) \land \neg \exists x (x < 0)$ is true in neither of the above three structures structures; in fact, it fails to be true in any structure whatsoever: No matter which domain of objects we take and which interpretation we assign to the symbols $<$ and $0$, the form of the statement $A \land \neg A$ makes it *inherently impossible to ever* become true.

To pick up your example, "The sky is red" is only coincidentally false in the actual world because our earthly sky just so happens to be blue, but it is possible to imagine a universe in which the atmosphere is constituted differently and the sky is indeed red: The sentence false in the real world, but it is not contradictory. In symbols, the sentence can be formalized as $p$, and will have a truth table with both a true and a falsy column.
On the other hand, $x \in S \land x \not \in S$ is another statement of the form $A \land \neg A$, and thus a contradiction: It is false in *all* structures, and thus also in our real-world conception of sets in standard ZF set theory. Its truth table has only 0's, no matter which value the component statements take.

The symbol $\bot$ is used to refer to a contradiction. And indeed, any contradictory statement is logically equivalent to (and can be transformed into, using rules of inference) both $A \land \neg A$ and $\bot$: All contradictory statements have the same truth table with only 0's in the last column.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Regarding the last point, what would a proof of the equiavlence look like? amWhy gave an example in the comments, but I don't see how it generalizes. If the proof is too elaborate, then a reference to a text would work too.

Comment: It depends on the proof system you wnat to use. With the standard equivalence laws as well as in natural deduction, the equivalence between $A \land \neg A$ and $\bot$ is one of the basic laws (often, $\bot$ is *defined* as shorthand for $A \land \neg A$). As another example, $\neg (A \lor \neg A)$ can be shown to be contradictory using the equivalence laws of De Morgan, double negation and commutativity: $\neg (A \lor \neg A) \equiv \neg A \land \neg \neg A \equiv \neg A \land A \equiv A \land \neg A \equiv \bot$.

Comment: A general proof that all contradictory statements are logically equivalent to $A \land \neg A$ is trivial: A contradiction has all 0's in its truth tables by its very definition; $A \land \neg A$ has all 0's in its truth table, as is easily verified; and two statements are logically equivalent iff they have the same truth table (again, by definition).

Comment: To take this further: All contradictory statements are logically equivalent to each other. The same goes for all tautological statements. (But not all contingent ones, because the lines in which they have their 1s and 0s may differ.)

Comment: The sky was red in California [recently](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/wildfire-sky-orange-bay-area-california-western-united-states/)

Comment: @lemontree Is that actually true, though? (A and B) and (A xor B) is a contradiction (it's false for all values of A and B), but how do you prove that it is equivalent to (A and B) and not (A and B), when (A xor B) has a different truth table to not (A and B)?

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, just write the truth tables out. Both will have 0 in all rows and are therefore equivalent. Replacing a subexpression by a logically equivalent one will leave the end result with the same truth values; but replacing a subexpression by an inequivalent one (such as not (A and B) vs (A xor B)) doesn't necessarily change the truth values of the whole expression either. Two statements may have the same final column even though their compound statements differ.

Answer (score 12):

The following is less concrete than lemontree's answer and amWhy's comments, which I think are more on-point. However, I do think the following is worth saying, so I'm putting it here.

The snappy version, as you suspect, is:

> A contradiction is never true in any situation. A statement is called *false* if it fails *in the particular situation (or class of situations) we care about* - but a false statement may nonetheless hold in a different situation (whereas a contradiction cannot).

Below I'll describe the two main ways of making this precise.

---

### Semantic version

The "semantic" view of logic is that a logical system $\mathcal{L}$ is used to **describe objects** (or **structures**): basically, such an $\mathcal{L}$ consists of a class of *sentences* $Sent_\mathcal{L}$, a class of *applicable structures* $Struc_\mathcal{L}$, and a relation $\models_\mathcal{L}$ between applicable structures and sentences with $$\mathfrak{A}\models_\mathcal{L}\varphi$$ being interpreted as "the sentence $\varphi$ is true in the structure $\mathfrak{A}$."

A *contradiction in the sense of $\mathcal{L}$*, then, is a sentence which is not true in any structure: a $\psi$ such that for every $\mathfrak{A}$ we have $\mathfrak{A}\not\models_\mathcal{L}\psi$. By contrast, when we decide to focus on a particular structure $\mathfrak{S}$, we say that $\varphi$ is false iff $\mathfrak{S}\not\models_\mathcal{L}\varphi$.

---

### Syntactic version

We can also refrain from talking about structures entirely. The "syntactic" view of logic is that a logical system is used to **manipulate sentences** (without necessarily assigning them particular meanings). Basically, such an $\mathcal{L}$ consists of a class of *sentences* $Sent_\mathcal{L}$ and a relation $\vdash_\mathcal{L}$ between sets of sentences and individual sentences with $$\Gamma\vdash_\mathcal{L}\varphi$$ being interpreted as "the sentence $\varphi$ is deducible from the set of sentences $\Gamma$."

A contradiction in this framework is then a sentence from which we can deduce anything: $\varphi$ is a *contradiction in the sense of $\mathcal{L}$* iff for all $\psi$ we have $\{\varphi\}\vdash_\mathcal{L}\psi$. By contrast, when we say that a sentence $\varphi$ is *false*, what we mean is that we have in mind some particular "background set of sentences" $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma\cup\{\varphi\}$ would let us deduce anything (think of this $\Gamma$ as our set of axioms).

---

### Connecting the two

It's worth noting that every semantic logic induces a syntactic logic: given a semantic logic $\mathcal{L}=(Sent_\mathcal{L}, Struc_\mathcal{L},\models_\mathcal{L})$ we get a syntactic logic $\mathcal{L}'=(Sent_{\mathcal{L}'}, \vdash_{\mathcal{L}'})$ defined as follows:

- $Sent_{\mathcal{L}'}=Sent_\mathcal{L}$, that is, we use the same sentences for both logics.
- We set $\Gamma\vdash_{\mathcal{L}'}\varphi$ iff whenever $\mathfrak{A}\in Struc_\mathcal{L}$ with $\mathfrak{A}\models_\mathcal{L}\psi$ for each $\psi\in\Gamma$, we have $\mathfrak{A}\models_\mathcal{L}\varphi$.

Note that this makes the two notions of "contradiction" line up: if $\varphi$ fails in every structure, then vacuously we have $\{\varphi\}\vdash_{\mathcal{L}'}\psi$ for every $\psi$.

There is also a way to go "syntax-to-semantics" which again makes the two notions of "contradiction" line up, but it's a bit less natural (basically we interpret "structure" as "set of sentences which doesn't deduce everything and is maximal with that property").

---

### A caveat

Actually, the above isn't entirely accurate: there are logical systems where sentences of the form "$P\wedge\neg P$" do **not** let you deduce everything (these are called "paraconsistent logics;" another relevant (hehe) term is "relevance logics"). This leads to a more nuanced notion of "contradiction" and its relatives. But that's a more advanced topic which I wouldn't approach before first understanding the classical picture.